# Flutter iOS Archive Error: Error (Xcode): Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode15

`Error (Xcode): Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'Runner': ExtractAppIntentsMetadata
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/datnguyen/WorkSpaces/project_template/flutter_getx_template/build/ios/Debug-develop-iphonesimulator/ImageNotification.appex' to '/Users/datnguyen/WorkSpaces/project_template/flutter_getx_template/build/ios/Debug-develop-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/ImageNotification.appex'
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “Thin Binary”
○ Target 'Runner' has process command with output '/Users/datnguyen/WorkSpaces/project_template/flutter_getx_template/build/ios/Debug-develop-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist'
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/datnguyen/WorkSpaces/project_template/flutter_getx_template/build/ios/Debug-develop-iphonesimulator/ImageNotification.appex' to '/Users/datnguyen/WorkSpaces/project_template/flutter_getx_template/build/ios/Debug-develop-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/ImageNotification.appex'

Raw dependency cycle trace:

target:  ->

node:  ->

command:  ->

node: /Users/datnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bhtoumdqsgiaregnjytyoapucbjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-develop-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ExtractedAppShortcutsMetadata.stringsdata ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug-develop:ExtractAppIntentsMetadata ->

node:  ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase7--cp--embed-pods-frameworks ->

node: /Users/datnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bhtoumdqsgiaregnjytyoapucbjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-develop-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/InputFileList-1739A84D50484D6E4E41EDFB-Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-develop-input-files-744cbbea3dded29901e6b34dae91a16a-resolved.xcfilelist ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug-develop:WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/datnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bhtoumdqsgiaregnjytyoapucbjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-develop-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/InputFileList-1739A84D50484D6E4E41EDFB-Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-develop-input-files-744cbbea3dded29901e6b34dae91a16a-resolved.xcfilelist ->

node:  ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase6-copy-files ->

node: <Copy /Users/datnguyen/WorkSpaces/project_template/flutter_getx_template/build/ios/Debug-develop-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/ImageNotification.appex> ->

CYCLE POINT ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug-develop:Copy /Users/datnguyen/WorkSpaces/project_template/flutter_getx_template/build/ios/Debug-develop-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/ImageNotification.appex /Users/datnguyen/WorkSpaces/project_template/flutter_getx_template/build/ios/Debug-develop-iphonesimulator/ImageNotification.appex ->

node:  ->

command: P0:::Gate target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49--fused-phase5-thin-binary ->

node:  ->

command: P2:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug-develop:PhaseScriptExecution Thin Binary /Users/datnguyen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bhtoumdqsgiaregnjytyoapucbjm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-develop-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-3B06AD1E1E4923F5004D2608.sh ->

node: /Users/datnguyen/WorkSpaces/project_template/flutter_getx_template/build/ios/Debug-develop-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist/ ->

directoryTreeSignature: ~ ->

directoryContents: /Users/datnguyen/WorkSpaces/project_template/flutter_getx_template/build/ios/Debug-develop-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist ->

node: /Users/datnguyen/WorkSpaces/project_template/flutter_getx_template/build/ios/Debug-develop-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug-develop:ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/datnguyen/WorkSpaces/project_template/flutter_getx_template/build/ios/Debug-develop-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist /Users/datnguyen/WorkSpaces/project_template/flutter_getx_template/ios/Runner/Info.plist ->

node: /Users/datnguyen/WorkSpaces/project_template/flutter_getx_template/build/ios/Debug-develop-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/ImageNotification.appex ->

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug-develop:Copy /Users/datnguyen/WorkSpaces/project_template/flutter_getx_template/build/ios/Debug-develop-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/ImageNotification.appex /Users/datnguyen/WorkSpaces/project_template/flutter_getx_template/build/ios/Debug-develop-iphonesimulator/ImageNotification.appex

`

Hi there,
I'm having a problem with XCode 15 and Flutter 3.13.6.
The first time I run it is not thing happen, but when I open XCode and and Notification Service Extension, It can't run anymore, event It's show
`Xcode build done.                                           22.7s Failed to build iOS app`

Answer (score 29):

In `Xcode>Targets>Runner>Build Phases`, I dragged `Embed Framework`, `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks`, and `Embed Foundation Extensions`  to be before "Run Script" as instructed [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/730974) .

Here is how it looks afterwards
[image]

Comment: thank you bro, after 4 hours working finally your solution helped me.

Comment: after trying several other methods this screenshot finally saved me!

Answer (score 4):

In my case, seems to resolve if you move up "Embed Foundation Extensions" just right below "Copy Bundle Resources" in the Build Phases.

Comment: this solution saved my life